# Set analyzers for _all field with NEST

Tags: nest

As described in the [_all field Elasticsearch Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#mapping-all-field).

> The _all fields allows for store, term_vector and analyzer (with specific index_analyzer and search_analyzer) to be set.

Is there a way to specify the `index_analyzer` and `search_analyzer` attributes on the `_all` field for a mapping with NEST? Specifically, I would like to be able to set the following for my index:

```
 {
     "model": {
        "_all": { 
             "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
             "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
        }

       ...
  }
```

I did not see anything that would allow for this in the Fluent Mappings. Can I set this manually if not via Fluent Mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from NEST 1.0 you can now do this:

```
var result = this._client.Map<ElasticsearchProject>(m => m
    .AllField(a=>a
        .Enabled() 
        .IndexAnalyzer("nGram_analyzer")
        .SearchAnalyzer("whitespace_analyzer")
        .TermVector(TermVectorOption.with_positions_offsets)
    )
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not setup the `_all` field correctly. It omits the `_all` field as an entry nested under `properties`. However, in looking at the documentation, the `_all` field is at the same level as `properties`, nested directly under the type name. Is there a way to get it to output at that higher level?

Comment: ahh this is an oversight on my part! Will make sure this is fixed in NEST 1.0

Comment: This is now implemented per https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/commit/98fd73a37c769698fa1946d0ed06525b0c29b729