# Using Nest, how to mimic an _all field that includes ngram tokens?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I believe it is impossible for the _all field to contain ngram tokens.  How can I mimic this behavior?

I have 7 types of entities, each with about 10 fields.  Of those 70 total fields, about 15 must support partial search (using an ngram index analyzer).  All fields will use the same search analyzer.

Is copy_to supported in Nest?  I don't see it. If so, can different fields have different analyzers?

My thinking so far: If copy_to is supported, all fields I want to search would be copied to a single field, one per type, called "aggregate".  The search query would specify a multifield search which included each of these aggregate fields.

Answer (score 1):

The `_all` field can in fact contain nGram tokens. You have the ability to define both the search and index analyzers for the `_all` field. Please see my previous question [Set analyzers for _all field with NEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920421/set-analyzers-for-all-field-with-nest) However, you will need to pull the [source for NEST](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net) and compile it to get this functionality, as it is not in the NEST 1.0.0-beta1 release on NuGet.

Comment: Does this override field level analyzers then?  I'm looking to use ngram on a name field and a standard analyzer on a orderID field, but include both in _all.

Comment: No, you can still set individual field level analyzers. They will all operate independently of each other as the fields that you mark to include in the _all field will get inserted using the source value at index time.